# Python 2.7: Unexpected behaviour in PriorityQueue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a PriorityQueue where it behaviour seems sensible overall:

```
   from Queue import PriorityQueue
   pq = PriorityQueue()
   pq.put((0, "hello"))
   pq.put((0, "oh"))
   pq.put((0, "h"))
```

if I do a pq.get() I get the elements in the following order:

```
pq.get()
h
pq.get()
hello
pq.get()
oh
```

This is weird, they are all the same priority yet they are not given in the order they are put in.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue):

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]).

Since you haven't specified priorities, it's returning them in sort-order of the data.

If you want to keep insertion order, one way to do it would be to keep a counter of insertions, and insert `(count, item)` tuples instead of the raw items.

Comment: I think the time that PascalvKooten mentioned could be used as the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Priority queue does a heapq sort (as pointed out in the comments) on the tuples (where the first value counts first, and when encountering equal in the first "column", will it compare the second).

You get the result since in sorting a string, `h < hello < oh` is `True`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html):

> Constructor for a priority queue. maxsize is an integer that sets the upperbound limit on the number of items that can be placed in the queue. Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until queue items are consumed. If maxsize is less than or equal to zero, the queue size is infinite.

You might actually consider adding a time constant to your actual priorities. E.g. if you have "solve problem" with priority 0, and "fix little bug" with priority 1, and more tasks in each, if you really cared about the order as you put them in, you can add a weighted time constant, or just add a really small value for number of tasks.

E.g. to add:

```
   import time
   pq.put((0 + time.time()*0.0000000001, "hello"))
   pq.put((0 + time.time()*0.0000000001, "oh"))
   pq.put((0 + time.time()*0.0000000001, "h"))
```

Comment: "Priority queue simply does a sort on the tuples" - not quite. It returns items in the same order as if it did a sort, but it uses a heap, which is more efficient for mixed insertions and removals than doing lots and lots of sorts.